# ios 7 bottom bar inside application appearance

Tags: ios, ios7, swipe, notification-bar

Is there a way to disable new notification bar in ios7 inside applicaton?
I don't want the new bar to show when user swipes from botton while inside my app.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using public API. And you shouldn't, as this is a universal feature across the operating system, across all software. There is no real option.

You can hide the status bar using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`. This will not display the control center immediately, however any swipe from the bottom would still show an arrow which, if swiped again, would open the control center.

[image]

If the user chooses, he or she can disable the control center in third party applications if he chooses to. You can add a recommendation page in your app, where you may suggest that.

[image]

Comment: Right, just curiosity: what if you really had a swipe function (from bottom to top) that displays / does something. The question is: does that take precedence over the OS function? I think no, but it's hard for me to accept that Apple would create such a function that forces developers to re-design their UI. Don't get me wrong, you are right with your answer. Just curiosity.

Comment: No, the OS always takes precedence. Like the notification center swipe gesture from top. I would recommend making a design change where a swipe from the bottom is not required.

Comment: But for example in Real Racing game it shows an arrow in the middle and when you swipe it again it shows notification bar.. So there is a way to hide it.

Comment: That only happens when the status bar is hidden. Is this the behavior you are seeking?

Comment: Also, it won't help because any swipe from the bottom will still display the arrow.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for the full hide,but arrows will do just fine.

Comment: Does anyone know if that arrow is available as a system image ?